# Filtering SQL statements on Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am sending too much data to AI, I checked that SQL dependency is eating all my points. I want to filter out all the SQL Select statements with a duration of more than 250 ms while keeping all the inserts and deletes for auditing purposes. I can filter by duration and type of command (SQL) but I don't know how to differentiate between selects, inserts and deletes. I can't find the property containing those while debugging. Any suggestion?

Code I am using below:

if (dependency.DependencyKind == "SQL" && dependency.Duration.Milliseconds < 250)

Comment: Are you logging SQL commands? If so, you can filter in dependency of SQL command. https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Filtering' feature in order to filter those dependency documents out.

You can read more about it here (including examples): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling/

Comment: I know, I am using Filtering. My issue is how to get the type of SQL command using Filtering.